# Firestore and Storage - Gallery

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-firestore

With my app, I upload text data to Firestore without problems. But I want to upload images. Bone type Social network.
What would you have to do to have the Firestore document connected to the Storage image?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Im sure by now you have realized that you cannot send images directly to `Firebase Firestore` or `Realtime Database`. This has been an underlying no-feature for Firebase. Instead you need to manage both `Firestore/RealtimeDatabase` as well as `Cloud Storage`

What I use in my apps instead is the following

**1. Link Firestore/Realtime Database to Cloud Storage**

Save a link to your cloud storage in a field in your firestore/realtime database.

```
person
    --personId1
       --name
        --image
             -- 0 - "mystorage/person1/image/<your-image>" //link to cloud storage bucket
             -- 1 - "mystorage/person1/image/<your-image>" //link to cloud storage bucket
```

Once you download for instance `personId1` to your device, you can go through the `image` field and use the paths in the `image` field to download the relevant photos.

Use this [link to the docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/) for cloud storage if you need it

**Note:** you can either save the images field as an `Object/Hashmap` or an `array`, depending on what you prefer.

Comment: I don't get it to be honest why to save the image field as an array or Hashmap, why can't I store it just as a string? And if I do, what are the downsides?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a small image, such as a profile picture, you can base64 encode it and save it directly to a Cloud Firestore document.  The document limit is 1Mb